# $scope.$apply() not calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a need for a custom click directive, which executes the passed code using scope.$apply().

```
$(elem).on('click', function(){
    scope.$apply(attrs.wdClick);
});
```

This works fine if I pass something like wd-click="something = !something". But when I try to call a $rootScope function it does not work, however it does work when using the default ng-click.

```
wd-click="$root.someFunction()" //this does not call the function but ng-click does
```

I have tried updating the directive to make it work

```
$(elem).on('click', function(){
    $rootScope.$apply(attrs.wdClick);
});
```

But this does not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attrs.wdClick` is a string, so passing it to `$apply` won't do anything. To call the function you can pass the string to `$eval`

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  scope.$eval(attrs.wdClick)
});
```

Comment: have the same problem, i tried $scope.$eval and $scope.$apply. no errors, nothing happens :| when i dump to console, i can tell that it is a function, not just a string

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code in function(){}

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    attrs.wdClick() // this is some sunction I suppose
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you want to call your rootscope method in an another controller? If I understand correctly, try to use this way :

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl1($scope,  $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.blah = 'Hello';
        $scope.yah = 'World'
    })
    .directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
            scope: {},
            controller: ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope) {
                console.log($rootScope.blah);
                console.log($scope.yah);
                
                $scope.test = function(arg) {
                    console.log(arg);
                }
            }]
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <my-template></my-template>
    </div>
    
    <!-- my-template.html -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
        <label ng-click="test($root.blah)">Click</label>
    </script>
</div>
```

Also you can try on jsfiddle, 
http://jsfiddle.net/mg74b/24/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to use attrs instead of a scope property?  Also, you should use $timeout instead of $apply.

```
angular
        .module('app', [])
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ['$timeout'];
function myDirective($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
        scope: {
            wdClick: '='
        },
        link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, element) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            $timeout(scope.wdClick);
        });
    }
}
```